# What is it that should be done here?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I have been following this [tutorial](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_an_editor_for_my_own_language%3F) to come up with a simple source code editor. (The feature that I want the most is keyword highlighting.) What I do not understand is the last part:

```
class Scanner extends RuleBasedScanner {
  public Scanner() {
     WordRule rule = new WordRule(new IWordDetector() {
        public boolean isWordStart(char c) { 
        return Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(c); 
        }
        public boolean isWordPart(char c) {   
            return Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(c); 
        }
     });
     Token keyword = new Token(new TextAttribute(Editor.KEYWORD, null, SWT.BOLD));
     Token comment = new Token(new TextAttribute(Editor.COMMENT));
     Token string = new Token(new TextAttribute(Editor.STRING));
     //add tokens for each reserved word
     for (int n = 0; n < Parser.KEYWORDS.length; n++) {
        rule.addWord(Parser.KEYWORDS[n], keyword);
     }
     setRules(new IRule[] {
        rule,
        new SingleLineRule("#", null, comment),
        new SingleLineRule("\"", "\"", string, '\\'),
        new SingleLineRule("'", "'", string, '\\'),
        new WhitespaceRule(new IWhitespaceDetector() {
           public boolean isWhitespace(char c) {
              return Character.isWhitespace(c);
           }
        }),
     });
  }
}
```

The instruction is as follows:

For each of the keywords in our little language, we define a word entry in our WordRule. We pass our keyword detector, together with rules for recognizing comments, strings, and white spaces to the scanner. With this simple set of rules, the scanner can segment a stream of bytes into sections and then use the underlying rules to color the sections.

Shed me some light please? I do not know what it is I have to do to set the desired keywords..

Comment: You need to supply the string array that here is called Parser.KEYWORDS; that's about it for a start.

Comment: Excuse me, does that mean I have to create a class named Parser where the string array named KEYWORDS resides? @ErnestFriedman-Hill

Comment: Doesn't matter where the string array lives; just define the array somewhere, and change "Parser.KEYWORDS" into a reference to wherever it is.

Comment: Why, thank you ever so much, Sir! It works. @ErnestFriedman-Hill